# How to show loader in reactjs and meteor?

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have a page where 3 recipes are listed along with more button. When more button is clicked more 3 recipes are listed. What i am trying to do is before listing more 3 recipes i want to show a spinner/loader icon but i could only change the text of button. How can i show loader icon as soon as more button is clicked and before those additional 3 recipes are listed. I am using meteorjs and reactjs.

**my code for this is**

```
export default class Home extends Component {
    constructor(){
        super();
        this.state = { limit:3 , loading:false }
        this.addMore = this.addMore.bind(this);
    }
    getMeteorData(){
        let data = {};
        data.recipes = [];
        data.recipes = Recipes.find({},{sort:{createdAt:-1}}).fetch();
        let recipeHandle = Meteor.subscribe('recipelist',this.state.limit);
        if(recipeHandle.ready()){
            data.recipes = Recipes.find({},{sort:{createdAt:-1},limit:this.state.limit}).fetch();
        }
        return data;
    }

    addMore(){
        this.setState({
                        limit:this.state.limit + 3, loading: true }, () => {
                        this.setTimeout(()=>{
                            this.setState({loading:false});
                        },2000);
                    });
    }
    render() {
        console.log('this.data.recipes',this.data.recipes);
        let recipes = _.map(this.data.recipes,(recipe) => {
            return <RecipeList key={recipe._id} recipe={recipe} loading={this.state.loading} />
        });
        return (
            <div className="row">
                <div className="intro blink z-depth-1">
                  <div className="row">
                    <div className="col l7">
                        <h1 className="heading flow-text blink">Sell your Recipe</h1>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div className="row">
                    <div className="col s12">
                        {recipes}
                    </div>
                </div>
                <button onClick={this.addMore} type="button" className="btn coral more">More</button>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
ReactMixin(Home.prototype, ReactMeteorData);
```

Comment: In `getMeteorData()` you could store the loading state: `data.isLoading = !recipeHandle.ready();`

Comment: Thanks for knowledge. I get it. I could make it work both way(one your way and another @omerts ) now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could remove the loading state, and just compute the loading state from the data: `{this.state.limit !== this.data.recipes.length && <img src="path_to_loader.gif" />}`

I am not sure where you want to show the loader, but for example you could do:

```
render() {
  console.log('this.data.recipes',this.data.recipes);
  let recipes = _.map(this.data.recipes,(recipe) => {
      return <RecipeList key={recipe._id} recipe={recipe} loading={this.state.loading} />
  });
  return (
      <div className="row">
          <div className="intro blink z-depth-1">
            <div className="row">
              <div className="col l7">
                  <h1 className="heading flow-text blink">Sell your Recipe</h1>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="row">
              <div className="col s12">
                  {recipes}
              </div>
          </div>
          {this.state.limit !== this.data.recipes.length && <img src="path_to_loader.gif" />}
          <button onClick={this.addMore} type="button" className="btn coral more">More</button>
      </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Where should i provide setTimeout so i can so loading state for some more sec ?

Comment: I don't think you need setTimeout, the first render will occur on setState, where you change the state to loading. After more data is loaded by Meteor another render should occur automatically (from what I understand about Meteor).